# Ionic capacitor Camera, File plugin_not_install

Tags: ionic-framework

```
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1100.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.5
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.5

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.3.0
```

I've been trying to let the user add images from the camera or gallery using this tutorial
(https://enappd.com/blog/camera-and-image-picker-in-ionic-apps/148/). When I run the application on the emulator, the error message (from ToastController) said 'plugin_not_installed'.

page1.ts

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from "@ionic-native/Camera/ngx";
import { File } from "@ionic-native/file/ngx";

export class Page1 extends OnInit(){
constructor(
    private camera: Camera,
    private actionSheetController: ActionSheetController,
    private file: File
){}

  async pickImage(sourceType) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    };
    await this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      (imageData) => {
        console.log(imageData);
        // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
        if (imageData !== undefined)
          this.img = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.presentToast(err);
      }
    );
  }

  async selectImage() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: "Select Image source",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "From Gallery",
          handler: () => {
            this.pickImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
          },
        },
        {
          text: "From Camera",
          handler: () => {
            this.pickImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
          },
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          role: "cancel",
        },
      ],
    });
    return await actionSheet.present();
  }
```

page1.html

```
<ion-card id="pictureFrame" (click)="selectImage()">
</ion-card>
```

Comment: uninstall the plugin and application .. and then install the plugin and rebuild the apk .. hopefully it will get fixed

Comment: okay, i will try :)

Answer (score 0):

downgrading to "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.4" worked for me